# email is coming with tags without interpretation

Tags: magento2, php, email, controllers

Guys I have a module for sending e-mail, that when sending the e-mail it is arriving with the html tags, example: br span, that is, it is not being interpreted. I think the code is read by php as a string, and sent as text, but I don't know how to fix it. I need help please. Below is my controller code....

```
$SenderText = $post['text']; 

 $text = "<span>";

        foreach ($senderItens as $itens) {
            $text .= $itens . "<br>";
        }

        $text .= "</span>";



$sender = [
 'itens' => $text
]

->setTemplateVars([

 'itens' => $text  
])
```

my html template has the following tag

```
<tr>
        <td>
            Products: {{var itens}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your email template just use like below

> {{var itens|raw}}

this will fix your issue

plese accept as a solution and upvote if it helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In setTemplateVars use itens instead of text (Use var that you are using in email html template)

```
$SenderText = $post['text']; 
$text = "<span>";
        foreach ($senderItens as $itens) {
            $text .= $itens . "<br>";
        }

        $text .= "</span>";
$sender = [
 'conteudo' => $text
]
->setTemplateVars([

 'itens' => $text  
])
```

**UPDATE:**
Use this in your html template

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
Products: {{var itens}}
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Good morning friend, I did it but it still shows as html tags when receiving the email :/

Comment: I have update the answer please implement this and let me know

Comment: it's already like this

Comment: it sends the email normally, but it does not translate the tags I used in the controller as html, i'm stuck on this for 4 days i can't solve, and I'm new to magento

Comment: Can you please update your question with all code of email template?